# Unable to insert data into PostgreSQL table through php heroku app

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to create a simple php application on heroku with postgresql back end.
I have created a connection to postgresql server with the provided credentials from heroku:-

```
<?php

class DB_Connect
    {
        private $db; 
        public function connect()
        {
          $host        = "";
          $port        = "port=5432";
          $dbname      = "";
          $credentials = "user= password=";

          $db = pg_connect( " $url $host $port $dbname $credentials"  );
          if(!$db){
             echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
          } else {
             echo "Opened database successfully\n";
          }
        }
    }

    $db1 = new DB_Connect();
    $conn = $db1->connect();

    $query = "insert into public.user_test(name,email) values('val','val@in.com')";
    $result = pg_query($conn,$query);
    echo $result;
?>
```

When i deploy the app on heroku, I get a Opened Database successfully message but nothing gets inserted into the table when I check the table using pgadmin.

I tried it with and without the schema name "public", but that didn't help either.

When I run the app locally by providing the local postgresql credentials, the table gets populated.

Comment: Just note that the `$db` from `$db = pg_connect..` is not the same as the one from `private $db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't return the connection in your connect method. Adding `return $db;` after the if condition should do the trick.

```
class DB_Connect
{
    public function connect()
    {
      $host        = "";
      $port        = "port=5432";
      $dbname      = "";
      $credentials = "user= password=";

      $db = pg_connect( " $url $host $port $dbname $credentials"  );
      if(!$db){
         echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
      } else {
         echo "Opened database successfully\n";
      }
      return $db;
    }
}
```